# sugcon 2017 Amsterdam

Tags: discussion

I am planning to attend sugcon 2017 in amsterdam. 
I need schengen visa to go to Amsterdam.
Is this conference come under Bussiness visa? If yes i need invitation letter from sitecore according to netherlands embassy website? 
http://www.vfsglobal.com/Netherlands/UK/Business-Visit.html

> Original and recent invitation from the Netherlands based company on
>   company letter head. The letter must explain the nature and duration
>   of stay and number of entries required. If the foreign business
>   partner is covering all expenses connected with your visit including
>   accommodation it must be stated in the letter.

Does sitecore provide this?

Answer (score 1):

That's great news. We support attendees coming from outside Schengen. We can provide you with an invitation letter for the embassy.

Could you use the contact form on sugcon.eu to get in contact with us:
http://www.sugcon.eu/contact-us/

Comment: I did 5 days ago, I haven't heard back from sitecore.

Comment: Oke, I can check with the organization. Are you on Slack chat  or Twitter (@pieterbrink123) so you we can connect.